# Change a ListItem in runtime

Tags: dojo

Using `dojox.mobile` I simply want to create a `ListItem`, and at a later point change the text.

I cannot get this to work as it simply doesn't change.

Code:

```
var listWidget = dijit.byId("list");
var listItem = new dojox.mobile.ListItem({
    id: "listitem_1",
    icon: "icon.png"
    moveTo: "anoterView",
    label: "Initial label"
});
listWidget.addChild(listItem);


var listItem = dijit.byId("listitem_1");
listItem.set("label", "this is an updated label");
```

Any ideas?

BR
calo

Comment: are you sure you meant routeItem in that last line?? Is that an error in your code or just your paste here?

Answer (score 2):

```
dijit.byId('routeItem').set("label","this is an updated label");
```

This has worked for me but different properties work in wierd ways! RightText can only be achieved through this method by setting the Icon can't!
Dave

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me for updating the rightText. I think should work to update the label as well

```
 var execListNode = document.getElementById("execCntLi");
 var rtText = execListNode.getElementsByClassName("mblListItemRightText")[0]; 
            box.innerHTML = execCnt;
```

Thanks
NJ